# Tkinter cannot close image when pressing keyboard key

Tags: python, tkinter

The objective here is to draw a rectangle using tkinter on the image and then press spacebar and close the image, but I can't close the window when pressing space.

I`m doing this for a Psychology experiment and lately I will have to save this image in a folder, if it is not too much to ask, I would be very grateful if you help me with this problem aswell... sorry

```py
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import sys


class ExampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.x = self.y = 0
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=512, height=720, cursor="cross")
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_button_press)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_move_press)
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_button_release)
        self.rect = None
        self.start_x = None
        self.start_y = None
        self._draw_image()

#   Space to destroy 
        self.canvas.bind("<space>", self.on_space_press)   

    def _draw_image(self):
         self.im = Image.open('./EFCTupright_04203d903.jpg')
         self.tk_im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.im)
         self.canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor="nw",image=self.tk_im)

#  Destroy image: 
    def on_space_press(self, event):
        app.destroy()

    def on_button_press(self, event):
        # save mouse drag start position
        self.start_x = event.x
        self.start_y = event.y

        # create rectangle if not yet exist
        #if not self.rect:
        self.rect = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, 2, 2, fill="", outline="red")

    def on_move_press(self, event):
        curX, curY = (event.x, event.y)

        # expand rectangle as you drag the mouse
        self.canvas.coords(self.rect, self.start_x, self.start_y, curX, curY)


    def on_button_release(self, event):
        pass



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ExampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably want to do the key binding on the window itself - the Canvas won't have key focus if the user hasn't clicked in it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your code.

Instead of

`self.canvas.bind("<space>", self.on_space_press)`

Use

`self.bind("<space>", self.on_space_press)`

I also added a save function to your code

```
def save_file(self):
    # This will draw a rectangle on the image
    self.draw.rectangle( self.rec_coords, outline=self.outline_color)

    # Name of the file and format you want to save as
    self.im.save("out_put.jpg","JPEG")
```

**Complete Code**

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageDraw
import sys

class ExampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.x = self.y = 0
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=512, height=720, cursor="cross", highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.update()
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_button_press)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_move_press)
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_button_release)
        self.rect = None
        self.start_x = None
        self.start_y = None
        self.outline_color = "red"
        self._draw_image()

        # Space to destroy 
        self.bind("<space>", self.on_space_press)   

    def _draw_image(self):
        self.im = Image.open('./EFCTupright_04203d903.jpg').resize((self.winfo_reqwidth(), self.winfo_reqheight()))
        self.tk_im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.im)
        self.draw = ImageDraw.Draw(self.im)
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor="nw",image=self.tk_im)

    # Destroy image: 
    def on_space_press(self, event):
        self.save_file()
        self.destroy()

    def on_button_press(self, event):
        # save mouse drag start position
        self.start_x = event.x
        self.start_y = event.y

        # create rectangle if not yet exist
        #if not self.rect:
        self.rect = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, 0, 0, outline=self.outline_color, tag="rect")

    def on_move_press(self, event):
        curX, curY = (event.x, event.y)
        # expand rectangle as you drag the mouse
        self.canvas.coords(self.rect, self.start_x, self.start_y, curX, curY)

    def on_button_release(self, event):
        pass

    def save_file(self):
        # This will draw a rectangle on the image
        for rect in self.canvas.find_withtag("rect"):
            self.draw.rectangle( self.canvas.coords(rect), outline=self.outline_color)

        # Name of the file and format you want to save as
        self.im.save("out_put.jpg","JPEG")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ExampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```